# Making ListView Items overlap wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to make a stack of cards. Adding the cards I want in the right order works, but I want the most bottom card to overlap with the card before it and be above it.

And the same thing all the way back to the first one, not including obviously.

Think of a stack of cards.
My XAML for now:

```
<ListView Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Background="{x:Null}" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Cards}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:CardView DataContext="{Binding}"/>
         </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that pretty easily with negative Margin. One way is to add Margin property to your `Card` type:

```
public Thickness Margin { get; set; }
```

And bind it in view:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <local:CardView DataContext="{Binding}" Margin="{Binding Margin}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

How you fill it in depends on your needs. Here's one simple way:

```
foreach (var model in Cards.Skip(1))
    model.Margin = new Thickness(0, -100, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. I didn't understand the index, what was it for?

Comment: @tjw, oh, that was my mistake. You don't need it there.